# jquery plugin basics tasks

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to develop a simple jquery plugin...

I read the jquery documentation and now I'm just trying to change the div where I appended the plugin, but I honestly don't know what's happening.

this is the jfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/9eLqm/

html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('dropdown').pifo_dropdown({'width': 300, 'fontsize' : 18 }); 
    $('dropdown').pifo_dropdown('show');
});
</script>


<div id="dropdown"> div</div>
```

javascript:

> (function( $ ) {
>       var settings = $.extend( {
>         'width'                 : 200,
>         'maxheight'         : 200,
>         'fontsize'          : 13,
>         'defaultlbl'            : 'Select an option'
>       });
>
> var methods = {         init : function( options ) {
>             settings = $.extend(options);           // Applying settings
>                     }   };
>
> ```
>  $.fn.pifo_dropdown = function( method, options ) {
>
> // Methods
> if ( methods[method] ) {
>   return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
> } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
>   return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
> } else {
>   $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.pifo_dropdrown' );
> }   
>
> this.fadeOut();
> ```
>
> };
>      })
>      ( jQuery );

anyone can help me? Thank in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can not use `id` element like `$('dropdown')` this. for using id u need to declare it with `$('#dropdown')` and suppose if you using class `$('.dropdown')`

**replace**

```
$('dropdown').pifo_dropdown({'width': 300, 'fontsize' : 18 }); 
$('dropdown').pifo_dropdown('show');
```

**With**

```
$('#dropdown').pifo_dropdown({'width': 300, 'fontsize' : 18 }); 
$('#dropdown').pifo_dropdown('show');
```

Comment: Thank you so much... I'm embarrassed... such a primary mistake :)